Can't echo same variable twice on one line
PORT=$(cat /root/EnvironmentConfigurations/mbc_back/.env | grep '^PORT=' | cut -d '=' -f 2)
echo $PORT:$PORT
OUTPUT IS-> ":6590" SHOULD BE-> "6590:6590"
I have tried to display 6590:6590 but i only got :6590 for some reason first one becomes empty also tried getting another variable from that file still the same result.

You can grep a file without cat, by the way
